# Javafx even lags when drawing on canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a drawing application in JavaFX. All is going well so far but a quite annoying thing is that when I use the standard draw tool it's like its pausing the animation on the canvas and it creates gaps where it doesn't draw anything. The gaps appear with even spaces or rather appears between even times.

Example:
[Screenshot of canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntc6N.png)

Minimal reproducible example:

- Main.java:

  ```
  package sample;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
  import javafx.scene.Parent;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class Main extends Application {

      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
          primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
          primaryStage.show();
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }
  }
  ```
- Controller.java:

  ```
  package sample;

  import javafx.fxml.FXML;
  import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
  import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
  import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

  public class Controller {
      @FXML
      private Canvas canvas;
      private int size = 30;

      public void draw(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (!mouseEvent.getEventType().getName().equals("MOUSE_RELEASED")) {
              double mouseX = mouseEvent.getX();
              double mouseY = mouseEvent.getY();
              GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
              gc.fillRect(mouseX - size/2, mouseY - size/2, size, size);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- sample.fxml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

  <GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="1080.0" onMouseDragged="#draw" onMousePressed="#draw" onMouseReleased="#draw" width="1920.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowSpan="3" />
     </children>
  </GridPane>
  ```

Does someone know how to get around this problem? I have tried to take the positions that makes the gap and fill it but it doesn't look good and not working super well either.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Draw Lines instead of rectangles and it will work without gaps. I used here the  `gc.strokeLine` method and stored the last clicked point by extending the standard Canvas object. (I didn't use your XML file since it has some web content to download in it)

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    MyCanvas can = new MyCanvas();
    can.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, ev -> {
             can.draw(ev);
             ev.consume(); //optional
         });
    Pane p = new Pane(can);
    
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p));
    primaryStage.show();
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

And here your custom Canvas object implementing the draw method:

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

private int size = 30;

private Point2D last;
private GraphicsContext gc;

public MyCanvas() {
    super(1280, 1280);

}

public void draw(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

    if (!mouseEvent.getEventType().getName().equals("MOUSE_RELEASED")) {
        GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setLineWidth(size);
        float mouseX = (float) mouseEvent.getX();
        float mouseY = (float) mouseEvent.getY();
        if (last != null) {
            gc.strokeLine(last.x, last.y, mouseX, mouseY);
        }
        last = new Point2D(mouseX, mouseY);
    } else {
        last = null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This works to some degree but i still get the "lags" and it becomes a straight line which can look good or really bad so is it really no other way to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't have 'lags' like you describe them on my computer or ever experienced them in JavaFX. Try not to run something else in the background on your JavaFX thread, just the Canvas ... but this is a wild guess, the code itself works without lags on my 8-year-old computer and my 10-year-old laptop.